# how to give auto increment for a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table which contains three field id(primary key),**number** and note.Id is auto increment.I want data in this table in which **number** field contain current date with five digit number.
For example current date is 24/11/2014,then my **first** entry become **201400001**,second will be 201400002 and so on.On next **year** it will be **201500001**,and so on.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: number is auto incremented as well as note.Id?

Comment: @shwetdalal I think the fields are id,number,note

Comment: oh sorry I miss read it.

Comment: 201400001 is a 9 digit number. Actually this cannot be done by mysql itself. The auto increment will do by front end like PHP

Comment: @Edrich shall i give varchar as type of number

Comment: Yeah, if you want a pattern like "000001" , "00002" your data type must be a varchar.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Using Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = initial_value" ?

Comment: Alter table is not the solution for his problem.